# Can Medoids be manually selected in PAM?

Tags: clustering, k-medoids

I'm currently running a cluster analyses on a dataset that contains variables of categorical and continuos values.I applied the well-established Gower’s dissimilarity coefficient to account for categorical and continuous variables in the dataset. Clusters were characterised using the Partitioning Around Medoids (PAM) algorithm and i used the silhoutte width plot to determine the number of clusters (which in my case was 6).

The dataset describes different types of fishing nets found in the ocean and the variables range from mesh size (mm) twine diameter (mm) colour, number of strands etc. When i print out the medoid types the selected objects are not all representative of the entire dataset and im worried this will throw off my interpretation of the output. For example all my medoids seem to have similar mesh sizes despite the fact that the range is between 5 - 1500mm. My question is would it be possible to pre determine the mediods before running the cluster analyses ?. Apologies if this question seems a little obvious or confusing to some i am very new to R.

By the way im using the cluster package

thanks in advance

Comment: If the medoids are pre-determined,  why do you need cluster analysis?  You just need to find the nearest medoid for your other data points. You can do that efficiently with a nearest neighbors classifier.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are correct if i knew my medoids i would not need to do a cluster analyses. The problem i'm facing, and possibly it did not come across clearly in my above question, is that my medoids are not predetermined, however my medoids that the cluster analyses has selected to be the best model do not appear to be representative of my dataframe. In this situation what are my options? and if there is a way to rerun the cluster taking into account nearest neighbours what code would i use for this?

Comment: Going back to comments. If you make a scatterplot of the points, you can color the points in different clusters with different colors. That might help you see what the clustering was using.  Is your data publically accessible so that I could look at it?

Comment: Maybe your similarity function needs to be improved? If you fix the medoids, you are not clustering anymore, but doing classification.

Comment: Also if you follow this link you can see the raw data but the first column was excluded from the analyses as this shows a turtle is entangled in a net or not and does not describe the net characteristics: http://oliveridleyproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Ghost-net-without-na.txt

Comment: The axes on the scatterplot above your silhouette plot are labeled x & y.  What do those mean in terms of your original variables?  Oh, I see,  you used TSNE to map to a 2-dimensional space.

Comment: Once i conducted the Gower scaling i then conducted a pam_fit command so im not sure what the x - y represent and i guess that could be half my issue. This is the code i used to generate the scatter plot above the silhoutte width plot. 
tsne_data <- tsne_obj$Y %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  setNames(c("X", "Y")) %>%
  mutate(cluster = factor(pam_fit$clustering),
         name = mydata$Turtle)

ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y), data = tsne_data) +
  geom_point(aes(color = cluster))

Comment: Since the clusters came out so distinct in the scatterplot, they must be different in _some_ coordinates.  Would you post the medoids?